# Syslog-ng Events Per Second Graphing

Tags: syslog-ng

I have a distributed syslog-ng setup and am trying to determine how many events per second (EPS) we are receiving on each one. I know that syslog-ng does some general performance statistic to /var/log/messages and you can also request this information on an ad-hoc basis. However it doesn't truly give me how many EPS I am receiving at that point in time. So I'm trying to determine what's the best/easiest way to get this information. It can be graph based or simply command-line based. Before I was feeding the syslog-ng data into Logstash on another server and I was getting the graph and EPS information, but would like to do something small scale on the syslog-ng servers themselves and not duplicate all of the data.

Thanks in advance,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Syslog-ng doesn't do that now. There is a discussion on the mailing list now how stars should work in the future.

Perhaps querying starts every minute and graphing the deltas is the best we have now.